# how to add a caption / thumbs up or down to featherlight

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, caption, featherlight.js

I wanted to add a caption below the featherlight modal image. I tried using the following code to do so, as many other posts on here suggested, but it did not work.

```
$.featherlightGallery.prototype.afterContent = function () {
            var caption = this.$currentTarget.find('img').attr('alt');
            this.$instance.find('.caption').remove();
            $('<div class="caption">').text(caption).appendTo(this.$instance.find('.featherlight-content'));
    }
```

Instead, I got the following errors in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
at main.js:62

featherlight.min.js:8 Featherlight: no content filter found  (no target specified)
```

---

Here is how I am inserting the images into my page. My plan is to include a thumbs up and down below the modal image, and I thought at least getting the alt tag to display correctly would be a good first step. If anyone could actually help with inserting a link/image instead of an alt caption that would be even better! Any help is greatly appreciated!

JAVASCRIPT

```
function putImages(){

if (ajaxCall.readyState==4){

    if(ajaxCall.responseText){
        // to separate the file names, with semicolons
        var resp = ajaxCall.responseText;
        var files = resp.split(";");
        // check if string isn't empty and add a thumbnail
        for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){

            if(files[i] != ""){

                document.getElementById("gallery").innerHTML += '<img class="myImg" src="/img/'+files[i]+'" width="198" height="198" alt="test" data-featherlight="/img/'+files[i]+'" />';
                picCount++;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Image Gallery -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12" id="gallery">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that `$.featherlightGallery` is `undefined`. You're not loading featherlight gallery properly, or if using just featherlight, then that's the option you should be changing.

Comment: So I changed `$.featherlightGallery` over to just `$.featherlight` and got a similar error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined` and `Featherlight: no content filter found (no target specified).` when clicking on images to bring up the lightbox. The lightbox seems to work fine, so I don't really know what this last error is about. The only problem I can really see is the lack of caption. Could this be because I am not using `<a>` tags?